# Concatenar colunas e algumas com valor NULL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, string, firebird, sintaxe

Estou fazendo um *select* e concatenando as colunas, quando uma coluna tem valor `NULL` (não tem valor algum ) toda a linha fica `NULL` segue um exemplo:

```
select 'teste'||CONTROLE||','||CODIGO||','||DATA||','||HISTORICO from tabela
```

Os resultados:

```
null
null
null
null
teste05,06501,2015-08-01,maria
null
null
null
teste09,01123,2015-08-01,ronaldo
null
null
null
teste13,07361,2015-08-01,tenório
```

é sabido que apenas a última coluna pode ter valor `null`, então queria que na primeira linha o resultado fosse conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
teste01,06501,2015-08-01,
teste02,07052,2015-08-01,
teste03,03574,2015-08-01,
teste04,04123,2015-08-01,
teste05,06501,2015-08-01,maria
teste06,...
teste07,...
teste08,...
teste09,01123,2015-08-01,ronaldo
teste10,...
teste11,...
teste12,...
teste13,07361,2015-08-01,tenório
```

O exemplo acima eu não consigo obter, só escrevi na mão mesmo para mostra o que eu esperava como resultado porque mesmo se todas as colunas fossem `NULL` ainda assim eu queria um resultado com o que eu concatenei ex: `teste,,,` se tudo fosse `null`.

Já tentei usar um `if`, tentei um case e nada. Ma [documentação](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/nullguide-testing.html) só achei algo que não serve para esse caso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa usar a função [`COALESCE(coluna, '')`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd15-coalesce.html).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Isso mesmo que eu precisava, obrigado !